# Expected tosses till HHH or THH

Tags: probability, expected-value, puzzle

> In a coin tossing game with a fair coin, find expected tosses till we get HHH or THH.

Source: [puzzledquant.com](https://www.puzzledquant.com/problems/clhudg7xg000gmm08jfcd42b6)

My approach: This can be thought of as geometric distribution since trials are independent and p is fixed. So, probability of getting $HHH$ or $THH$ is $1/4 (=2 * 1/8)$. So expected tosses till we get either should be $4$. However, answer says expected tosses to get $HHH$ is $14$ and $THH$ is $8$. I am confused, how is this true?

Comment: These aren't independent processes.  Indeed, the only way to end on $HHH$ is if you get that on the first three tosses.  Other than that case, you are just searching for $THH$ and a simple recursion will suffice.

Comment: Look up "Penney's paradox" or "Penney's game."

Comment: You should do some experiments with some real coins, and then you will have some intuition about this.

Comment: You can run your experiments online here:  https://penneys.github.io/

Comment: So, could we have said that expected tosses till H is 2 (since p=1/2 here)? What about expected tosses till HH (then this would also not be independent so we cannot say expected tosses = 4 ) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of getting $THH$ is much higher because the sequence of flips is continuous; that is, the trials are not independent.

If I have a chain of coin flips in which neither sequence has appeared, such as below:

$...HTHTT$

then it would be impossible for the sequence $HHH$ to appear before $THH$ appears.